# Pairs of positions of equal elements of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a row vector `A` in Matlab containing possibly repeated integers. I would like your help to construct a matrix `B` reporting all possible pairs of positions of equal elements of `A`. As stated in the comments below, the hard part is that I don't want to list in `B` "redundant" pairs.

Let me explain better with an example.

```
clear
A=[100 101 100 100 101 200];
```

We can see that

```
%A(1)=A(3)=A(4);
%A(2)=A(5);
```

Hence,

```
 B=[1 3; 1 4; 2 5];
```

or, equivalently,

```
B=[1 3; 3 4; 2 5];

B=[1 4; 3 4; 2 5];
```

I am indifferent among getting any of the three vectors `B` reported above.

Notice that I don't want

```
B=[1 3; 1 4; 3 4; 2 5];
```

as one of the pairs among `(1,3), (1,4), (3,4)` is redundant, i.e., if `A(1)=A(3)` and `A(1)=A(4)`, then `A(4)=A(3)` and similarly for other combinations.

I tried with `unique` but none of the outputs delivered by `unique` seems to give the desired matrix. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like to use loops, As suggested in the @Wolfie's [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51671402/6579744), you can use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[~,~,idx]=unique(A,'stable');
B = accumarray                                      ...
    (                                               ...
        idx(:),                                     ...
        (1:numel(A)).',                             ...
        [],                                         ...
        @(x)                                        ...
        {                                           ...
            [repmat(x(1),numel(x)-1,1) x(2:end,1)]  ...
        }                                           ...
    );
result = vertcat(B{:})
```

Answer (score 2):

The part which requires thinking here is the redundant pairings. The easiest approach to remove redundant pairings is to have one key index for each value, and link all matching values to that index.

In the case of your example, this means using the following relations

```
% A(1) = A(3)
% A(1) = A(4)
% A(2) = A(5)
```

It's implied by any equivalences to the first of each value that, for instance, `A(3)=A(4)`.

To do this, we can use the last indexing output from `unique`, then loop through to set up this equivalence indexing. See the below code, with comments for understanding:

```
% A is the input row vector
A=[100 101 100 100 101 200];
% Get the 'unique' indexing output
[~, ~, juA] = unique(A);
% Set up output as cell so we don't have to worry about how many rows each
% equivalence will take up.
B = cell( max(juA), 1 );
% Loop through all of the unique indices
for ii = 1:max(juA)    
    % Get indices where the value is equal to the current value   
    k = find( juA == ii );  
    % Output for this value is [1 x; 1 y; 1 z; ...] where x/y/z are indices
    % of equivalent values
    B{ii} = [repmat(k(1), numel(k)-1, 1), k(2:end)]; 
end
% Concatenate cell array B to be a 2 column numeric array
B = vertcat(B{:});
```

Output:

```
>> B = [1 3; 1 4; 2 5]
```